# iPhone: Hide toolbar

Tags: iphone, toolbar

I have class A which has toolbar(created progmatically) & with
property(nonatomic,retain) Ihave added that toolbar as a subview in class A In another class B. I want to make toolbar of class A hidden

How to do that ? i am using but it isn't working? please give me
solution. I am using Xcode 4.3.1

I am writing this code in class B

But its not Working

```
ClassA *aobj= [[classA alloc] init];

[aobj.toolbar sethidden:yes];
```

Comment: pass the object of class A let it be a to B using delegate method and make [a.toolbar sethidden:yes];

Comment: Assuming ClassA and ClassB are both views?

Comment: @arshad Please explain a bit your solution I am not able to understand  it
If possible post it as a Answer
Thanks for showing interest in my question

Comment: @Dinesh Kaushik add extern id context; in classA.h then add id context; classA.m (@place where global varriable are declared) and add context = self; in ViewDidLoad of classA. Then import classA.h in classB and [context.toolbar sethidden:yes];,here you are making object of class a as exernal varriable.This is not a good method.If you need better method pls explain how and where you are creating classB.

Comment: @Arshad:  Thanks a lot Arshad for your Valuable comment with the help of which I solved the problem
I made a object of class A  (obj)  in a Singleton class. Then  in viewdidload of class A   i did  obj=self;
In class B i used   obj.toolbar.hidden=YES;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `extern id context;` in classA.h then add `id context;` classA.m (@place where global varriable are declared) and `add context = self;` in ViewDidLoad of classA. Then import classA.h in classB and `[context.toolbar sethidden:yes];`,here you are making object of class a as exernal varriable.This is not a good method.If you need better method pls explain how and where you are creating classB.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of your code is that you create a new instance of `ClassA` and try to set the `UIToolBar` hidden on this new instance which is never showed somewhere.

What you need is an object which points to the `ClassA` which is showed on the screen.

So try something like this:

```
- (id)initWithClassA:(ClassA *)classa {
     if ((self = [super init])) {
          [classa.toolbar sethidden:yes]; 
     }
     return self;
}
```

And when you make an instance of `ClassB` you use this:

```
ClassB classb = [[ClassB alloc] initWithClassA:self];
```

---

If you want to hide the toolbar only when `ClassB` did loaded you can create a variable of `ClassA` at `ClassB.h` and set it to the parameter which is provided in you self-created init-method:

```
- (id)initWithClassA:(ClassA *)classa {
     if ((self = [super init])) {
          instanceOfClassA = classa; 
     }
     return self;
}
```

Comment: I have understanded the problem but i am not able to use your code
Where exactly to use this code
As class has already a -(id)initWithNibName   method

Comment: I think you're initializing `ClassB` somewhere in `ClassA` and then you're going to show `ClassB`. Now instead of using `[[ClassB alloc] initWithNibName:@"..."]` you use `[[ClassB alloc] initWithClassA:self]`. What you do is to pass `self` (self is the original `ClassA`-Object) to `ClassB` where it's stored and where you can use it to hide the toolbar. A class is a kind of descriptor how your object will look like, the object is based on your class and has its specific place in memory, if you create a new instance you'll get a new place in memory, you understand?

Comment: Thanks A lot for your valuable answer it really helped me solve my problem. Your answer properly explained where i was going wrong and what should be done to solve the problem
Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

`[[classA alloc] init];` creates a new object of ClassA. This new object of ClassA has his own new toolbar. This is not the previously created toolbar.

To have access to the old toolbar from ClassB you need to pass the old object of ClassA to ClassB. *(You could also use delegate method, where on run time it will decide which class to call)*

Using `initWithNibName` parameter passing method:

in `ClassB.h`

`UIViewController           *parentController;`

```
-(id)initWithNibNameAndParentController:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil:(UIViewController*)controller;
```

In `ClassB.m`

```
-(id)initWithNibNameAndParentController:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil:(UIViewController*)controller {
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
parentController = controller;
}
return self;
}
```

In ClassA `initWithNibName` like this:

```
objB = [[ClassB alloc] initWithNibNameAndParentController:@"..." bundle:nil :self];
```

Now from ClassB.m hide your ClassA toolbar as your wish

```
[((ClassA*)parentController).toolbar sethidden:yes];
```

Comment: thanks A lot for your valuable answer it really helped me solve my problem. Your answer properly explained where i was making the mistake
Thanks a lot again

Answer (score 0):

try setting frame of the tabbar. like set the frame to bounds beyond the screen will hide the control. Hope this will help you.

Comment: :thanks for showing interest in my question
With the help of above answers i solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```